# Issues Mounting NFS Server: Server Side MacOS, client side SAMA5D27 board

Tags: mount, nfs, macos

I am trying to mount an NFS server with the Server side being my laptop running MacOS Mojave, and the client side being my SAMA5D27 board running Ubuntu Linux built using Yocto.

I've assigned an IP address to the SAMA5D27 board, and am able to ping the SAMA5D27 board from my laptop, and vice versa. So they are visible to each other.

On my laptop, I've edited the /etc/exports file to say the following:

```
/Users/mntpnt    192.168.1.100(rw, no_root_squash)
```

I then started nfsd on the laptop by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo nfsd enable
$ sudo nfsd start

$ sudo nfsd status 
nfsd service is enabled
nfsd is running (pid 24885, 8 threads)
```

On the SAMA5D27, I run the following command (server IP: 192.168.1.8)

```
$ showmount -e 192.168.1.8
```

it shows:

```
Export list for 192.168.1.8:
/Users/mntpnt 192.168.1.100
```

I then try to do the mounting using the following command on the client SAMA5D27:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu ApNF 9 00:37:14 2020S: bad mount option value specified: minorversion=1

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 872
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt
```

I have also tried editing the permissions in the /etc/exports so that it now reads:

```
/Users/mntpnt    -network 192.168.1.8 (rw, no_root_squash)    -mask 255.255.255.0
```

and I also did a `$ sudo nfsd restart` on my MacOS after that.

So now the access denied error on the SAMA5D27 goes away, but I'm now not getting a response at all:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr  9 00:45:43 2020NFS: bad mount option value specified: minorversion=1

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
```

This seems to go on in a loop until I get a connection timed out.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Edits:

@NasirRiley - Yes, I did do sudo nfsd restart before trying again.

Here's the output of the command you suggested:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu NFr  9 00:04:29 2020S: bad mount option value specified: minorversion=1

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 718
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt
```

And here is the output of

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt 

mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr  9 00:06:33 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 718
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt
```

Comment: There may be other issues but first, the IP address in `/etc/exports` should be that of the client and not the server. Replace what you have with the client IP address: `/Users/mntpnt   192.168.1.10(rw,no_root_squash)`, restart the service, and run the mount command again. Keep in mind that 192.168.1.10 is just a placeholder. Use whatever the Ubuntu machine's IP address is.

Comment: @NasirRiley I have tried this. $ showmount -e 192.168.1.8 returns : /Users/mntpnt 192.168.1.100. Still either times out or access denied.

Comment: Did you restart the service after making the changes? Edit your question and add the output of `sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt`. Do not post it in the comments so that it doesn't get lost.

Comment: @SamyuktaRamnath can you please test explicit version 3 in the options like `mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 ....` ?

Comment: @NasirRiley have added the edits to my question as you requested.

Comment: @binarysta I have added the output when I explicitly call out the version of nfs as you suggested.

Comment: /etc/exports:  "/Users/mntpnt    192.168.1.0/24(rw, no_root_squash)" if you want to share the hierarchy to the 192.168.1.0 hierarchy, not '-network and '-mask'